# deserializing generic types protobuf c#

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers

I searched for an answer to this question but I didn't see many specific answers to it. My question is relatively simple: given data serialized in the protobuf format, is it possible to deserialize it without knowing the data type?

It seems that I can serialize any type without knowing what it is by doing:

```
public static byte[] SerializeData<T>(T arg)
{
    try
    {
        using (var testStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            Serializer.Serialize(testStream, arg);
....
```

Is there a way to do this such that Serializer.Deserialize(stream) (or something of that sort)?

Comment: `It seems that I can serialize any type without knowing what it is` It **does** know what it is. Through either `T` or `arg.GetType()`. The reason you can't easily do what you want is that the same protobuf payload would be valid for many different types. You can't _infer_ what type it is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to embed type information for de-/serialization purposes using protobuf-net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7078615/how-to-embed-type-information-for-de-serialization-purposes-using-protobuf-net)

Comment: @mjwills That makes sense -- so I would have to include the type information with the object itself either when serializing it or within the class itself?

Comment: One technique (that I wouldn't recommend) is to have a proto within a proto. The outer proto contains the type information and the payload for the inner proto.

Comment: @mjwills that's *essentially* what `Any` is (except: with a url); I haven't added `Any` support to protobuf-net to date.